# Postgres Relationship query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables A and B where the relationship is one to many (A -> many B). Table `"A"` contains columns `id, name` and table "B" has `id, a_id(fk), is_off(boolean)`.

Now, I want to get id of `"A"` which has all `"B"`'s `is_off = true`.

I tried this one `select a.id from A a inner join B b on a.id = b.a_id where b.is_off = true` But it only returns even if an "A" has an item (B) which has is_off = false;

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. A subquery is probably what you're looking for:

Test data

```
CREATE TABLE a (id int PRIMARY KEY, name text);
CREATE TABLE b (id int, a_id int REFERENCES a(id), is_off boolean);

INSERT INTO a VALUES (1,'foo');
INSERT INTO b VALUES (42,1,true),(1,1,false);
```

Your query would return all records if at least one of the `b` records fulfil your join and where clauses:

```
SELECT * FROM a  
JOIN b on a.id = b.a_id 
WHERE b.is_off;

 id | name | id | a_id | is_off 
----+------+----+------+--------
  1 | foo  | 42 |    1 | t
(1 Zeile)
```

If you intend to exclude all `a` records that contain at least one `is_off = true`, you can use `NOT IN` with a subquery, but as suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name (see comments below) you could use `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * FROM a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT a_id FROM b WHERE a.id = b.a_id AND is_off);

 id | name 
----+------
(0 Zeilen)
```

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` is typically more efficient and also doesn't have nasty surprised when the sub-query returns NULL values.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for the hint. you're totally right! I will edit my answer